# Angular Multiple Modules - How can I get an external NPM component to work across multiple modules in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have successfully followed the instructions here [ngx-avatar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-avatar) to install this component in one of my app's modules.

The module is called **Core**. The component that it is in is called learnerbar. Within the learnerbar html I have placed the tag

`<ngx-avatar facebookId="123456789" size="150"></ngx-avatar>`

This is working perfectly.

I now also want to use it in a different module called **Features**.

The component is called my-profile and within the html file I have place the identical tag as above.

Firstly I imported the **AvatarModule** into the Features Module in exactly the same way as in the Core Module.

Import statement & added to imports array.

The one in the Core module works fine, The one in the Features module gives me the error

`'ngx-avatar' is not a known element:`

Secondly I removed all references to AvatarModule in both the Core and the Features Module, then created a **Shared** module where it imports the Avatar Module, adds it to both the imports and exports arrays, then I imported the shared module into both the Core Module and the Features Module and still the Core one works but the features one does not. It still says

`'ngx-avatar' is not a known element:`

What am I doing wrong? Can some external components only be used in one module. Can anybody make this component work across 2 different modules?

**EDIT:** Code added

Shared Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MenuItems } from './menu-items';
import { AccordionAnchorDirective, AccordionLinkDirective, AccordionDirective } from './accordion';
import { HighlightDirective } from './accordion';
import { SpinnerComponent } from './spinner.component';
import { Courses } from './courses';

import { AvatarModule } from 'ngx-avatar';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HighlightDirective,
    AccordionAnchorDirective,
    AccordionLinkDirective,
    AccordionDirective,
    // SpinnerComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    HighlightDirective,
    AccordionAnchorDirective,
    AccordionLinkDirective,
    AccordionDirective,
    AvatarModule
    // SpinnerComponent
   ],
   imports: [
    AvatarModule
   ],
  providers: [ MenuItems, Courses ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Core Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule } from '../shared/module/material.module';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { FullComponent } from './layouts/full/full.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


import { MenuItems } from '../shared/menu-items';
import { HighlightDirective, AccordionAnchorDirective, AccordionLinkDirective, AccordionDirective } from 'src/app/shared/accordion';
import { HeaderComponent } from './layouts/full/header/header.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './layouts/full/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { SpinnerComponent } from '../shared/spinner.component';
import { FiltercoursesPipe } from './pipes/filtercourses.pipe';
import { LearnerbarComponent } from './layouts/full/learnerbar/learnerbar.component';
// import { AvatarModule } from 'ngx-avatar';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { ProfileComponent } from './layouts/full/profile/profile.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FullComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    // SpinnerComponent,
    // HighlightDirective,
    // AccordionAnchorDirective,
    // AccordionLinkDirective,
    // AccordionDirective,
    FiltercoursesPipe,
    LearnerbarComponent,
    ProfileComponent
   ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    // AvatarModule
    SharedModule
  ],
  exports: [ FiltercoursesPipe],
  providers: [ MenuItems ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

Features Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { TrainingPlanComponent } from './training-plan/components/training-plan.component';
import { LisElearningComponent } from './learning-items/components/lis-elearning/lis-elearning.component';
import { LisInstructorComponent } from './learning-items/components/lis-instructor/lis-instructor.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { CourseLibraryComponent } from './course-library/course-library.component';
import { ResourcesComponent } from './resources/resources.component';
import { MyProfileComponent } from './my-profile/my-profile.component';
import { SupportComponent } from './support/support.component';
import { Courses } from '../shared/courses';
import { FiltercoursesPipe } from '../core/pipes/filtercourses.pipe';
// import { AvatarModule } from 'ngx-avatar';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    TrainingPlanComponent,
    LisElearningComponent,
    LisInstructorComponent,
    CourseLibraryComponent,
    ResourcesComponent,
    MyProfileComponent,
    SupportComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    // AvatarModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  providers: [ Courses,
     FiltercoursesPipe ]
}) 
export class FeaturesModule { }
```

**EDIT2**: - Because I am on a deadline with work I moved the My Profile folder to the same folder as the learnerbar and changed the routing. Now it is using the Core Module and it is working. A workaround and not an answer to my question though.

Comment: please show your SharedModule code

Comment: Please share the module ts code of both modules for us to help you. Components can be included as many times as you want.

Comment: Your approach with the shared module is correct and also what Angular suggests you do: https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

Comment: I have updated with my code. Thanks

Comment: I have found that sometimes when I am refactoring modules like this I need to restart ng serve. VSCode plugins/linters say everything is fine but the dev server complains until its restarted. I agree with Frank, your modules setup looks good.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisNewman. I have tried this trick but to no avail. I have resorted to moving the component to the Core folder and changing the routing. Maybe it's a bug with this particular npm package as I've never had this problem before.